# How can I set a directory through a function?

Tags: r, working-directory

When I start my PC, my current directory is:

```
C:\Users\kieken\Documents
```

However, my working directory for R should be:

```
C:\Users\kieken\Dropbox\science\R programming
```

For this case only, my data is stored in the following folder:

```
C:\Users\kieken\Dropbox\science\R programming\specdata
```

I have to to write a function that uses only the last part of this path:

```
pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 43:44)
```

How do I use a variable "directory" in my function definition so that when I assign "specdata" to the variable "directory", everything works fine?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file.path`:

```
path <- "C:\\Users\\kieken\\Dropbox\\science\\R programming"
directory <- "specdata"

mypath <- file.path(path, directory, fsep = "\\")
# [1] "C:\\Users\\kieken\\Dropbox\\science\\R programming\\specdata"
```

Then you can use

```
setwd(mypath)
```

Comment: but when I add: setwd(file.path) ; I get the error: Error in setwd(file.path) : character argument expected

Comment: > path <- "C:\\Users\\kieken\\Dropbox\\science\\R programming"
> directory <- "specdata"
> file.path(path, directory, fsep = "\\")
[1] "C:\\Users\\kieken\\Dropbox\\science\\R programming\\specdata"
> setwd(file.path)
Error in setwd(file.path) : character argument expected